# How to make a shape in a vb6 application that resembles an Excel shape

Tags: vb6

I am trying to make a shape like a "call-out" box to use in a VB6 application. I can use the "Shape" tool to make a rounded-corner rectangle, but I would like to add the "V" shape at the bottom and have it all incorporated in the shape. A good example is the call-out shape used in Excel.

I have also used an image tool with a BMP in it, but still have the square corners of the image tool. I can't figure a way to do this and hope some out there knows how...???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karl Peterson has code and explanation on creating an irregularly shaped object. It uses API calls, not just native VB controls.

See http://vb.mvps.org/samples/PolyBtn/.